# Regex matching problem

Tags: regex

Say I have the following SQL output:

```
(12, 'name'),
(233, 'name2'),
(2, 'name3'),
...
```

How do I match the numbers with REGEX in order to remove them? I would like the result to look like:

```
('name'),
('name2'),
('name3'),
...
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: in which programming language?

Comment: It doesn't matter. I need a piece of REGEX code. I'm a newbie in REGEX and I don't seem to manage myself in doing this.

Comment: @linkyndy, regular expressions are not a programming language. You can *match* a string, but you cannot *manipulate* a string without a programming language that will use the regular expressions.

Comment: @linkyndy, so it's fine to post a snippet of Haskell code (with regex)?

Comment: @link: [There are many different dialects of regular expressions, all subtly different. Therefore, when asking questions,  ̲a̲l̲w̲a̲y̲s̲  **include the speciﬁc programming language or tool** (e.g., Perl, Ruby, Python, Java, Javascript, vi, emacs, sed, lex, ɢɴᴜ grep, etc.) you are using. Otherwise you may get answers that won’t work for you.](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info)

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstandings. Basically I need to use the Find&Replace tool in Dreamweaver, with 'Use regular expression' checked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, to match the numbers use this:

```
\(([0-9]+,\s*)'.*'\)
```

That one grabs any numbers, a comma, and any whitespace that occurs after the comma. As for how to *replace* that with an empty string, it depends heavily on what you are running this with (PHP, Perl, sed, etc...)

Comment: Thank you! Basically I need to use the Find&Replace tool in Dreamweaver, with 'Use regular expression' checked.

Answer (score 1):

Replace: `/\(\d+,\s('[^']*')\)/` by: `($1)`

I'm afraid I can't make it any more usable without knowing the language you're using.

Comment: Thank you! Basically I need to use the Find&Replace tool in Dreamweaver, with 'Use regular expression' checked.